# Issue troubleshooting problem using .C in R

Tags: r, c

I am trying to write a function in `C` that I can call in `R` and am having trouble figuring out why my result is not what I expect it to be. I assume the problem must be coming from my `C` file and so maybe that file needs to be altered to get it to work correctly? Here is my setup:

I have a file called m1.c that contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>

void m1(double *x1p, double *x2p, double *fx)
{
    double x1 = *x1p;
    double x2 = *x2p;
    double temp = 4*pow(x1,2) - x1 - x2 - 2.5;
    fx = &temp;
}
```

I compile it using the following command from terminal:

```
R CMD SHLIB m1.c
```

and then call it from `R` using the following code:

```
dyn.load("m1.so")
.C("m1", x1=1,x2=2,fx=3)
```

However, the result of running the code in `R` is the following:

```
> .C("m1", x1=1,x2=2,fx=3)
$x1
[1] 1

$x2
[1] 2

$fx
[1] 3
```

Now what I was hoping for was that `$fx` would have been -1.5, i.e.,

```
> x1 = 1
> x2 = 2
> 4*x1^2 - x1 - x2 - 2.5
[1] -1.5
```

but I am getting 3. Again I'm sure the problem is in my C file but I can't quite understand what I am doing wrong. All I want to do is evaluate `4*x1^2 - x1 - x2 - 2.5` for whatever value of `x1` and `x2` gets inputed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the *address* of `temp` to the pointer `fx` which is local to your function. Instead you want to assign the *value* of `temp` to the memory location `fx` points to, i.e. you should do: `*fx = temp` in the last line of your function.